# How to make sure that my header does not change when I decrease the browser width?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, header, styling

When I shrink or contract the browser horizontally, my header kind of collapses. The links on the header get listed on top of each other from up to down and the header expands vertically down, hiding some of the content on the page. 
How do I make sure that the header's shape stays the same ?
Here is my header HTML and my CSS stylesheet:

```css
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/* mixins, variables */

/* universal */

html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}
section {
  overflow: auto;
}
textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}
/* typography */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  line-height: 1;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #3BB9FF;
}
p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.7em;
}
/* 
    footer{
    background-color: #222;
    div ul li{
    display:block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    }
    }
    */

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* miscellaneous */

.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
/* forms */

input,
textarea,
select,
.uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
input {
  height: auto !important;
}
#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has-error;
  .form-control {
    color: $state-danger-text;
  }
}
/* articles */

.container1 {
  opacity: 0.75;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 30px 75px 75px 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.container1 p img {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.container2 {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0px 75px 20px 100px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  /*#F8F8F8;*/
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 30px 75px 75px 100px;
}
/*Search*/

.search {
  padding: 6px 15px 6px 30px;
  margin: 3px;
}
.lighter,
.light,
.dark {
  width: 95%;
  height: 50px;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" , href="#">KREDIBLE</a>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
             MENU <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <%=l ink_to "Home", root_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%=l ink_to "About Us", about_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%=l ink_to "Contact Us", contact_path %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%=l ink_to "Subscribe", '#' %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%=l ink_to "Tags", tags_path %>
        </li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li>
            <%=l ink_to "Log out", logout_path %>
          </li>
          <% else %>
            <li>
              <%=l ink_to "Log in", login_path%>
            </li>
            <%end%>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <%=l ink_to "Subscribe", '#' %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use min width for the head div and to set it on value before collapsing to

Comment: How exactly do you do that ?